# Image with a centered text on of the google maps android version 2

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

In my monodroid project I try to add an image with a centered text to a specific lat/lng of google maps version 2.

With version 1 I add this by creating image and lable in a view and adding this view to the map as a subview.

But In new version we can not add subviews to the map. So how we can add such items to map?

**EDIT**

Actually I want to show something like this:

[image]

how can we add such markers with centered text on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [DemoIconProvider.java](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/source/browse/android-maps-extensions-demo/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/demo/DemoIconProvider.java) and `getIconData` function. It does basically the same what you see on your screen or here:

[image]

As always you will have to translate this from Java world to C#.